# Custom SharePoint 2010 theme?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, customization, sharepoint-designer

I would like to create a custom theme for SharePoint 2010. My theme is quite complex, created with background images and a quite different look and feel from the standard theme.
I have read that you can create themes with MS PowerPoint, is the tool right for me or should I work directly with the master page?
Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Involving PowerPoint in such a process would most likely be a big mistake. You should use Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010, it's free.

**64 bit version**, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=566d3f55-77a5-4298-bb9c-f55f096b125d

**32 bit version**, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d88a1505-849b-4587-b854-a7054ee28d66&displaylang=en

Designing a complex SharePoint template is hard work and requires lots of planning and good structure.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do so much with SharePoint when it comes to designing and building custom themes. If you need to have deep control over the theme - which is necessary for complex layouts - go straight to using custom CSS, images and possibly make Master Page changes (although this is rarely recommended).

Also, if you are going to take this fully custom route, make a copy of the default files and then customize the duplicates. If you modify the default files, when you update SharePoint to newer versions, there's a good chance your code will be overwritten by the updates.